# Entity Framework with a base entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Our team is working on implementing a code-first EF framework over an extensive existing database schema. One of the things we would really like to have is a base interface which  all our different entities will implement. All that we intend to define in this basic interface is an **Id** field and a **Name** field since all our database tables have some concept of both of these properties. There are a lot of benefits to this approach because there are a great many cases in our application where all you need from an object is its Id and some descriptive text (its 'Name') so being able to program to the interface rather than to the implementation can provide quite a bit of flexibility.

The problem arises because not all the tables in our schema have integer-based PKs, some have strings, guids, etc. So there's no way we can define a true 'type' for the Id field in our interface other than object that can accommodate all the possibilities. The issue then becomes that EF doesn't like the idea of an object as its PK so it complains when trying to specify HasKey(o => o.Id).

Is there anyway that you guys can think of to accomplish what we are trying to pull off here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use generics.

```
public interface IEntityBase<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can implement it like this

```
public class IntKeyEntity : IEntityBase<int>
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class StringKeyEntity : IEntityBase<string>
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

//etc
```

Comment: OK but then the interface forces you to the type of TKey...so assume for a moment that I change your interface to not use TKey and make Id of type 'object'. I can then simply pass around collections of that interface, for example: List<IEntityBase>. But in your implementation I can't do that, I have to choose the type I want to pass around: List<IEntityBase<int>> or List<IEntityBase<string>> etc. This kinda defeats the purpose because then you have to have knowledge of what the underlying type is and in that case why have an interface at all?

Comment: Are you saying that you are going to make one list with multiple types of objects in it?  What is the use case for this?  How would you perform comparisons against it?  Or are you concerned about having a shared method that returns a List of entities that can be used with any type?  You can make that method generic as well to solve the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you could modify the question to include some example code of how you want to use this.